# Xcode hidden feature

Tags: xcode

Many times I have seen this screen in Xcode. However, I don't know how to reproduce this or use this feature.

[image]

Comment: Watch session 402 *Working Efficiently with Xcode* of WWDC 2012 (yes twelve). There are described some of the "hidden features".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens when you do `SHIFT+ALT+CLICK` on a file in the *project navigator*.

When this panel appears, you can click on the boxes or on the "+" to open the file in a different view.

Comment: Shift + Alt + click is showing + sign and doing selection. So, are you sure these are keys? @Eric D.

Comment: Great Ans. I was inside Code. Now working. I am up voting. can you see another of mine question @Eric D.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I could help. I will have a look at your other questions later, yes.